# Tailwind CSS technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a horizontal rule with some text in the middle. For example:

```
----------------------------------- my title here -----------------------------
```

Is there a way to do that in Tailwind CSS?.